# Would undecidability in ZFC of the Laver Table conjecture imply its truth/falsity?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

The Laver Table conjecture is the conjecture that the first-row periods of Laver Tables are unbounded. Richard Laver proved in ZFC + rank-into-rank that it holds, but it is not known whether it is provable in ZFC by itself. But suppose someone proves that it is undecidable in ZFC by itself. Would that imply that the Laver Table conjecture is true/false?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the situation is with Laver tables, but there are plenty of instances where the undecidability of some proposition in ZFC would lead to it being "true" in a meta theoretical sense: see this MO post about RH https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79685/can-the-riemann-hypothesis-be-undecidable

Comment: Don't know anything about it, but [the statement given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laver_table#Are_the_First-row_Periods_Unbounded?)  looks to be $\Pi_2^0$, not $\Pi_1^0$ or $\Sigma_1^0,$ so if you're hoping for something along the lines of what happens with the Riemann hypothesis, seems unlikely unless there's some way to reduce its complexity.

Comment: Truth is relative a model. In arithmetic we have "the standard model" against which to judge truth. How do you decide what is true for ZFC?

Comment: @Asaf These are arithmetic statements.